# Use of @import for html/css fonts in Firefox with Noscript (Google fonts do not render)?

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

Resources like https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ note that CSS `@import` rule can be used for fonts, in particular Google fonts:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

So, I tried to write the following minimal example (stored at local PC in say `/tmp/ttt.htm`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700);
body {
  /*font: 18px/27px 'Oxygen', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 Testing a font here
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I open this in Firefox 42 with NoScript - even if/when I allow the `file://` protocol - I get a rendering like this:

[image: ff-css-font]

... which is to say, it is as if `@import` has been completely ignored; the same happens if I open http://fonts.googleapis.com in a different tab, allow it in NoScript there, and then I go back to the local HTML and refresh it there. However, if I open a new instance of Firefox like:

```
firefox -no-remote -P "some other profile" /tmp/ttt.htm
```

... then the font is properly rendered.

Is there any way to render this example properly in Firefox in NoScript - once NoScript permissions are given?

Answer (score 2):

NoScript blocks webfonts by default. This includes both by @font-face and @import. It's a configurable preference:

```
NoScript menu → Options... → Embeddings tab → Forbid @font-face
```

This is because the huge FreeType font library was not originally designed to load untrusted content over the web. It has had known vulnerabilities during the past 5 years and exploits could surface in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, got it - actually, when this page is loaded, there is a little yellow indicator on the NoScript icon, even *after* permissions have been given for `file://` (and so the NoScript icon is not crossed out with red):

[image: ff-noscript-blk]

That means that there are "Blocked Objects" - so one should just hover over that menu entry, and then can allow the font URLs; and then everything works as expected...